# Partial class entity framework propertychanged

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

With database first scenario, I have a many - many relation and use EF as ORM & DAL:

Customer: ID, Name, Address ||
Product: ID, Name ||
CustomerProduct: CutomerID, ProductID

I add a custom property to the  Product entity class , called  Isincludedforcustomer.

```
  public partial class Product: EntityObject 
{
    public bool isincludedforcustomer;
    public bool Isincludedforcustomer
    {
        get { return isincludedforcustomer; }
        set {isincludedforcustomer= value; }
    }
```

When a Customer is selected, I have a method to assign the new property.

```
 IsProductinclinframe(Displayedcustomerproducts, products);
```

How can i implement property changed to this property ?

Comment: If the below answer is satisfactory, please mark it as answered and/or give it an upvote.  This community thrives on its reputation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally put a call to the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the property.

```
public partial class Product: EntityObject, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public bool isincludedforcustomer;
    public bool Isincludedforcustomer
    {
        get { return isincludedforcustomer; }
        set 
        {
            isincludedforcustomer= value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("Isincludedforcustomer");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```